# Замечания к или на?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Замечания к конструкции изделия или замечания на конструкцию изделия

Answer (score 4):

Замечания НА ...-устаревшее употребление, в современном русском языке слово ЗАМЕЧАНИЕ управляет сочетаниями с предлогами К и ПО.

Возможны варианты: замечания к конструкции изделия,замечания по конструкции изделия, замечания по поводу конструкции.

Answer (score 0):

Если "конструкция изделия" это некий документ, который одна сторона предоставляет другой (обычно оно так и есть), то "замечание на" - вполне употребительное и даже предпочтительное управление с точки зрения профессионального жаргона.

Comment: По Д. Н. Ушакову  - замечания 2. только множественное число на что-нибудь Комментарии, ученая критика ( слово книжное , устаревшая форма ). Замечания на книгу.